# Android: How to Extract the data in 1 row with 2 columns

Tags: android

Here are my codes for my Search Activity

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
  {
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
  {
                                                                  // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
  }
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
  int start, int count, int after)
  {
  // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
  }
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
  int start, int before, int count)
  {
  textlength = search.getText().length();
  array_sort.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < listview_array.length; i++)
  {
  if (textlength <= listview_array[i].length())
  {
  if(search.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
  (String)
  listview_array[i].subSequence(0,
  textlength)))
  {
      array_sort.add(listview_array[i]);
      }
   }}

  listContent1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
  (Search_Food.this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_sort));
  }

  });
```

my onclicklistener code

```
 AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                 Search_Food.this);
          adb.setTitle("Food Item");
                  adb.setMessage("Selected Food is = "
                  + listContent1.getItemAtPosition(position));
                  adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                  adb.show();
```

my Dbadapter

```
public LinkedList<String> search(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LinkedList<String> results = new LinkedList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String search = string;
    try{
        cursor = this.sqLiteDatabase.query(true, MYDATABASE_TABLE , new String[] { KEY_ID , KEY_FOODNAME , KEY_CALORIES  }, KEY_FOODNAME  + " = ?" + "COLLATE NOCASE", 
                new String[] { search }, null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0 && cursor.moveToFirst()){

            int foodName = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FOODNAME );
            int keyColories = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CALORIES );

           // boolean moveToNext = cursor.moveToNext();
            //do{
                results.add(
                    new String(

                       cursor.getString(foodName) + "                              " +
                        cursor.getString(keyColories)
                    )
                );
            //}while(moveToNext);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(APP_NAME, "An error occurred while searching for "+search+": "+e.toString(), e);
    }finally{
        if(cursor!=null && !cursor.isClosed()){
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

now when i click a data on my searched listview, i want to extract the getitemposition into 2 and thats my columns. the food name and the calories. how can i separate the 2 values.

answers please. help. thank you

Comment: Did you already get the answer?

Comment: no sir @FestusTamakloe

Comment: should use SimpleCursorAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @HoanNguyen how would i use the simplecursoradapter there? help?

Comment: @FestusTamakloe sir i emailed you again

Comment: Do you want 2 columns in your list view, one with the name of food and the other the number of calories?

Comment: @HoanNguyen sir how can i use SimpleCursorAdapter on the  onTextChanged event, im having a problem conforming the ArrayAdapter for the cursor?

Comment: what is the definition of listview_array?

Comment: @HoanNguyen ha? i didnt get that sir?

Comment: If you want your listview to have 2 columns, one with the name of food and the other the number of calories and since you query the database, it maybe better if you change your code to use SimpleCursorAdapter. You use listview_array in for (int i = 0; i < listview_array.length; i++), I just want to know what it is.

Comment: actually i have 2 columns there. i just want to use simple cursor adapter on the ontextchane event an i dont know how to do it

Comment: @FestusTamakloe did you get my email sir?

Comment: yes i get i am still working on it

Comment: what did you send me? in the code that you send me there is still the problem that i solve for you some days ago. didn't?

Comment: its still the same project sir, in the email, ive written my new problem @FestusTamakloe

Comment: yes but the problem that i resolve for you is still there. I thought you've made some changes on the project?

Comment: oh, thats what you mean, i didnt change your codes cause it might not work so i left it as it is. @FestusTamakloe

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26743/discussion-between-festus-tamakloe-and-michelle-mo)